# apache mod_rewrite problem for the url

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mod-rewrite

As i am trying to rewrite a url into search engine friendly but i am not getting the proper form like. for example originally my url will be like this....

```
http://www.playtoongames.com/getscore.php?game_name=MarioVsSonic
```

The above url i am requesting from the flash game. so while i am requesting this url from flash game the html content comes in wired format like this http://www.playtoongames.com/getscore.php?game_name=MarioVsSonic instead of coming like this..
http://www.playtoongames.com/getscore
now i want to make this into this form like...

```
http://www.playtoongames.com/getscore/MarioVsSonic
```

For the above thing to happen i have created a .htaccess file and written the code like this...

```
RewriteRule ^get_name/([^/\.]+)/?$ getscore.php?get_name=$1 [L]
```

Regards,
phphunger

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the rewrite mode on in .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

And after this define your rewrite rules.

Comment: I have written the rules as follows..RewriteEngine On and RewriteRule ^get_name/([^/\.]+)/?$ getscore.php?get_name=$1 [L]

Comment: @phphunger : I think you don't need to have `^` at the start of regex, but this should work (if it does not, try to change the regex and you will soon find out where the problem is).

Answer (score 0):

The following rule will do the job to rewrite
http://www.playtoongames.com/getscore/MarioVsSonic
into
http://www.playtoongames.com/getscore.php?game_name=MarioVsSonic

```
RewriteRule ^getscore/([^/\.]+)/?$ /getscore.php?get_name=$1 [L]
```

Compare to your rule and see where you have made a mistake.

Comment: @LazyOne: i am sure the rule is right. Means it rewrites dynamic url to static url...

Comment: @phphunger: Well, I do not think so. This is your URL (part of it):  **getscore/MarioVsSonic** and this is your rule (part of it): **^get_name/([^/\.]+)/?$**. Unfortunately I do not see **get_name** in that URL

Comment: @LazyOne: yes i want to get in this (http://www.playtoongames.com/getscore/MarioVsSonic) form instead of like this (http://www.playtoongames.com/getscore.php?game_name=MarioVsSonic).. Could you please show me how to write the rule...

Comment: @phphunger: The rule is in my original answer -- have you tried it yet? `RewriteRule ^getscore/([^/\.]+)/?$ getscore.php?get_name=$1 [L]
`

Comment: @LazyOne: I have tried your original answer, but still no luck.. RewriteRule ^get_name/([^/\.]+)?$ /getscore.php?get_name=$1 [L]

Comment: @phphunger: Why do you keep trying to use ^get_name/ if you need ^getscore/ instead? -- That is the only difference between the rule you wrote and what I offered.

Comment: @LazyOne: Now i have modified my .htaccess code as follows.. RewriteRule ^getscore/([^/\.]+)/?$ /getscore.php?get_name=$1 [L] .. one thing is i am requesting a page called this http://www.playtoongames.com/getscore.php?game_name=MarioVsSonic .. now i want to redirect it to static form. could you please open up the url and see the difference between this dynamic url and static url like http://www.playtoongames.com/play/Scooby_BMX_Action ...

Comment: @phphunger: I see -- you want to have the score table together with all HTML design around, not just table on it's own. For this you need another page/script. I see 2 options here: 1) change the rule to redirect to the correct page (maybe you have showscore.php and this needs to be used instead) or 2) update the current getscore.php so it includes the whole page design when generates results table.

Comment: @LazyOne: Here what the thing is i have 2 pages called newscore.php and getscore.php. Here the getscore.php will display all the high score results. as i have already developed for other website. Thats working fine but the thing is its not search engine friendly url's. For reference you can view the highscores of that page.. http://www.startonlinegames.com/play.php?id=4187 .. check this site and click the highscores link in the game..then you will be redirected to the high scores page...with html content around it...

Comment: @phphunger: Do you have `get_score_1.php` on this site? if so -- change your rule a bit: `RewriteRule ^getscore/([^/\.]+)/?$ get_score_1.php?get_name=$1 [L]`. If not -- create/copy such file and use appropriate rewrite rule.

Comment: @LazyOne: No no..actually i have a file called getscore.php. for that file i have created a rule called RewriteRule ^getscore/([^/\.]+)/?$ /getscore.php?get_name=$1 [L]

Comment: @phphunger: Yes, but that file does not produce whole page, only results table. So, you have to edit this file to make it generate whole design (like it is done on get_score_1.php on another site). I do not think that simple url rewrite will help you here since the functionality is not implemented. As simple as this.

Comment: @LazyOne: So what shall i do? Could you please give me any suggestions...Its eating up my mind since 2 days....

Comment: @phphunger: change your `getscore.php` so it does the same job as `get_score_1.php` on that second site (simple copy-paste may do -- but it depends on how it was coded). I cannot give more specific/exact advice -- my previous comments are full of suggestions already.